# Replace numbers after a character using re.sub() on a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of numbers stored in a list and I want to delete the all the numbers after `.`
The list is,
`['08-52-05.173735', '09-01-22.68835', '09-10-34.145061',]` and I want to delete everything after `.`.Below is the code I am using,

```
ignore_ms = [re.sub(r'(?<=\.).*$', ' ', y) for y in timestamp]
print (ignore_ms)
```

where `timestamp` is the list above. However, the result I get is,

```
['[', "'", '0', '8', '-', '5', '2', '-', '0', '5', '. ', '1', '7', '3', '7', '3', '5', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '0', '9', '-', '0', '1', '-', '2', '2', '. ', '6', '8', '8', '3', '5', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '0', '9', '-', '1', '0', '-', '3', '4', '. ', '1', '4', '5', '0', '6', '1', "'", ',', ' ',
```

Whereas the result I want is `08-52-05., 09-01-22., 09-10-34.`

Any idea what is wrong with the code above?

Thanks.

Comment: Will there be more dots or only one?

Comment: Your code returns something different - https://ideone.com/EnNfmq. Looks like `timestamp` is a string in your code. Not sure but you might want [something like this](https://ideone.com/zfced1).

Comment: Yes `timestamp` is a string. I believe you need to pass a string to `re.sub`? No idea whay it was returning the output as mentioned but your second link gives me what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try using `str.split`:

```
l = ['08-52-05.173735', '09-01-22.68835', '09-10-34.145061']
print([i.split('.')[0]+'.' for i in l])
```

Comment: @Marceline why?

Comment: Look what Op's expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead go with a simpler approach avoiding regular expressions with:

```
l = ['08-52-05.173735', '09-01-22.68835', '09-10-34.145061',]

[i[:i.rfind('.')] for i in l]
# ['08-52-05', '09-01-22', '09-10-34']
```